# Naming and metadata in a wizard flow

Tags: interaction-design, workflow, wizard

In a short wizard flow (4 steps), should the option for naming the wizard and other metadata (description, etc) come as the initial step or as a final step? I'm of the opinion that it should be a final step as personally, I'd want to go setup the wizard first-fine tune my settings and **then** give it a name and description according to the way I have set it up. 
I've seen the same behaviour on desktop softwares too. For eg - A new Word/Sketch/Excel file only asks you to name your file as a final step.

However, my teammates disagree and think that it should be the initial step. Are there any such case studies that would help answer my question or help prove my point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question recently.

I think it's also connected to the mental model/experience level of the user.

If he's exactly knowing what he is up to (also in terms of what configuration possibilities are there) then it can be good to first let him enter his "mission statement", but if the naming can be influenced by the configuration and he's not aware of all steps I'd opt for specifying the name at the end.

In my case it was not a multi-step wizard but I still choose to first configure and then name the entity

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the user choose?

"Would you like to name your item now?

Skip"